# Moodle Web Services Function

Tags: api, moodle

Moodle 2.0 has its web service function [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services#Web_services_functions), but is it possible for me to create something specific or create a function which has not yet been defined??

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is possible. Check this documentation: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_and_a_web_service_function This applies to Moodle-2.0 also.